# How to define props interface with passed state/setState values?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm currently learning TypeScript and I found a problem in my app, after adding React.FunctionComponent to my components, there occured an error with my Props interface

```
Type '({ value, setValue, }: Props) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{}>'.
   Types of parameters '__0' and 'props' are incompatible.
      Type '{ children?: ReactNode; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Props': value, setValue ts(2322)
```

There is part of my code:

```
interface Props {
    value: string
    setValue: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>
    children: React.ReactNode
}

const SearchInput: React.FunctionComponent = ({
    value,
    setValue,
}: Props) => {}
```

I tried using only ReactNode, I tried using JSX.Element, but nothing works, could someone explain me where is the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: remove children from interface, and define SearchInput like this: `const SearchInput: React.FC<Props> = ({value, setValue}) => {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`React.FunctionComponent` is a generic component, you need to pass your `Props` to it: `React.FunctionComponent<Props>`. This also allows you to omit type annotation for function argument, since it can be derived automatically:

```js
const SearchInput: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = ({
    value,
    setValue,
}) => {}
```